# NextJS, How inject Authorization header before next.config rewrites happens?

Tags: microservices, http-proxy, nextjs-rewrites

I'm using **NextJS** to build our Frontend.
The **NextJS** API just provides basic checks and then redirects to proper micro-services.
But I'm struggling to find the proper approach.

Since we are using Next 12 I think **next.config** rewrites is a nice fit, but I need to augment the `req` with an Authorization header before the rewrites.

Is that even possible?
Or perhaps there's a better solution for this case that I think is a fairly common scenario having a middle-end redirect to proper API.

Comment: Did you find an elegant solution to this? If so would you mind sharing as I'm in a similar situation.